# How to find the position of number in a string list?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

```
 a = ['+321','+09e8','\sdf5234','6']
```

I want to convert it into a list of all numbers. In other words, remove all non-digit characters from all the strings from the list. The result should be a list of integers not strings.

```
[321,98, 5234, 6]
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: +09e8 is a representation of 9*10^8 (900,000,000). Do you want to keep it as that?

Comment: no, e is the letter e

Comment: I had a look at your previous questions. None of them show any effort from your side. They are all like "I have this, I want that, please do this for me". Please read again [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and stop treating SO as a free coding service.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank for your comment. I will definitely ask good questions next time ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub`

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: a = ['+321','+09e8','\sdf5234','6']

In [3]: [int(re.sub('[^0-9]','',x)) for x in a]
Out[3]: [321, 98, 5234, 6]
```

Here `re.sub('[^0-9]','',x)` will replace all the characters other than numbers(0-9) from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple and easy to understand like this will do the trick...

```
a = ['+321','+09e8','\sdf5234','6']
b = []
c = ''

for item in a:
    for char in item:
        if char.isdigit():
             c += char
    b.append(int(c))
    c = ''

print(b)
```

It loops through every item in the list `a` and loops through each character of `a`. It checks if the character is a number and if so, adds it to the string to add to the output (`b`)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, you can use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) with a list comprehension:

```
a = ['+321','+09e8','\sdf5234','6']

res = [int(''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])) for x in a]

[321, 98, 5234, 6]
```